# Which library to create data-visualization at a in-city level?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-driven

Hi all I'm a newbie in data-visualization. I am looking for a graphics library in JavaScript that supports data-visualization at an city level, I have found some (like D3js) but all seem to only support the creation of data at a country level and not city level (like the scale of Google map city zoom's level).

Maplace would be a great library but I am looking for something closer to common JS.

Would be great if anyone's got a hint, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean BY "In-city" like geo-visualization there are plenty of options:

- Cesium.js
- Three.js
- Leaflet.js
- d3.js
- raphael.js

try to search more on google but those are commonly used combinedly or individually.

> **A good data visualization means a good story telling**